# How to modify the style of the glow of input text field when focused?

Tags: css

How to modify the style or remove it of the glow of input text field when focused? I am using chrome. I tried borders and shadows but it did not change. Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/FNZD6/2/

```
input[type="text"]:focus.normal100{


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the `outline`, it is a CSS3 property. ( http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp )

```
input[type="text"]:focus{
    outline: red dotted;
}
```

You can style in a similar way you do with `border`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FNZD6/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the outline "glow" from all inputs with this rule:

```
input {
    outline: none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FNZD6/3/

Comment: I'd put `input:focus {...`, because he seemed to want to remove it when the input was focused only, although it seems unlikely that he'd have a glow when the input was not focused. Anyway, I think this is the way, +1.

Comment: I think most of the time when people want shadows or borders, they will use the box-shadow or border rules. OP seems to know enough to specify pseudo classes if he needs to. :)